# Configuring firefox to use a chain proxy

Tags: firefox, http-proxy, socks

I live in college and I access internet through a local http proxy. I want to access internet through external http/SOCKS5 proxies which are freely available. How to configure Firefox to do that?

Scenario:

```
My_comp <-->local http_proxy <--> external http_proxy <--> internet
```

Comment: is it mandatory to use local proxy for you to access the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to access an **External Proxy** behind an **Internal proxy** is to **SSH** External Proxy (if remote SSH enabled) and bind the connection to a specific port in your system. Thereafter, use the **port** and **127.0.0.1** as Network Options (Socks5) for Firefox.

If the system you've is Linux, type in **Terminal** `ssh -D Port_no user@server_address server_port`, where,

- **Port_no** is the binding port you can select for the system, try a port greater than 1024;
- **user** is the username provided by external proxy;
- **server_address** is the IP address of the external proxy;
- **server_port** is the port where the Server is receiving the SSH connection;

For Windows,many prefer **Putty**, but I would not be able to assure how it will work.

**About Putty** : `PuTTY is an SSH and telnet client, developed originally by Simon Tatham for the Windows platform.`

**Link for Putty** : [Here](http://www.putty.org/).

Comment: thanks Firelord! Is there any other method than this because proxy servers usually dont give such access.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaKodur I was thinking do you want access to a personal choice of External Proxy or else, VPN and TOR wouldn't do any bad? Otherwise, I'll try looking for such answer.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://http-tunnel.sourceforge.net/)? This talks about HTTP Tunneling, which we need here to achieve the goal.

Comment: [This](http://www.csparks.com/FirewallTunneling/index.xhtml) is the closest I can get of right now. Its about the usage of HTTpTunnel tool which possibly can help you to tunnel your system right to external proxy.

Comment: i dont want to use TOR or VPN. and the above mentioned solutions were quite useful for me. For now i think the problem is solved by your solution. Thank you ! But if you can find a solution in which there is no need of http-tunnel server outside the firewall it would be very grateful! what i exactly need is as i asked in the question with minimal or no extra installation of any softwares

Answer (score 0):

Without access to your university proxy configuration, I don't think it would be easy. You need to install a local proxy, that would chain to your external proxy, while passing all the data through your network proxy. I only know that you can do something similar with Tor (configure your browser to use Tor, configure Tor to use your proxy and a relay), but none of the most popular proxies (ie, Squid or Privoxy) does this.

Comment: thanks Braiam! Yup! i know tor! b.t i want specifically the connection configuration i asked in the question. above