# How to setup user and password for proxy server in Chrome/Chromium in headless mode via argument?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, selenium

I'm using Selenium to automate some stuff, i need to use proxy but my proxy use **Basic access authentication** so i need to put user and password, i already using: `--proxy-server=http://127.0.0.1:8001` arg to setup proxy server, doing some research i found this arg: `--proxy-user-and-password` but it seems that is invalid. Is possible to configure this via arg?

Comment: Here are solutions that you could try and let me know if one works or is at least relevant for you. [post1](https://www.guru99.com/selenium-proxy-authentication.html), [post2](https://botproxy.net/docs/how-to/setting-chromedriver-proxy-auth-with-selenium-using-python/), [post3](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/32484/how-to-login-with-http-proxy-using-selenium).

Comment: Hi @harrymc, i saw yours links, but don't work for me because i trying to use chrome in headless mode.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's not currently possible: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/net/docs/proxy.md#proxy-credentials-in-manual-proxy-settings

> Most platforms' manual proxy settings allow specifying a cleartext
>   username/password for proxy sign in. Chrome does not implement this,
>   and will not use any credentials embedded in the proxy settings.
>
> Proxy authentication will instead go through the ordinary flow to find
>   credentials.

Workarounds that come to mind:

- Manually create a profile with the right setup, copy the folder, and point Chrome to it via the `--user-data-dir` option.
- There are extensions that do the proxy login automatically as soon as the browser is opened.
- Spawn `stunnel` locally and put it "in the middle" (Chrome --no pwd--> stunnel --user:pwd--> real proxy). See [How to chain proxies with Firefox or Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1260279/how-to-chain-proxies-with-firefox-or-chrome)

If you're curious and want to try it out (who knows, maybe Chrome will support it one day!) the URL would have been `http://username:password@127.0.0.1:8001`

Comment: The user:password@ip don't work :(

Comment: Try setting up a profile and copying it, or spawning stunnel (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

- Edit

[image]

```
search_form = browser.find_element_by_id('search_form_input_homepage')
search_form.send_keys('username')
search_form.send_keys('password')
search_form.submit()
```

See more [here](https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/)

Maybe using inputs with `Sendkeys` in **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**?

[image]

- Selenium- + Proxy + Firewall + Username + Password == **[Déjà vu to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55993431/how-to-authenticate-a-firewall-web-page-via-powershell-selenium-chrome-driver/55997694#55997694)**

```ps1
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$obj = New-Object -com Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Run('Chrome'),9
Start-Sleep -m 700
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}") 
Start-Sleep -m 250
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("username") 
Start-Sleep -m 250
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("pasword")
Start-Sleep -m 250
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("~")`
```

You may need to adjust the timeout and the keys needed to navigate your interface

```ps1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}{TAB}") interface/selenium 
Start-Sleep -m `550
```

- **[SendKeys Method in PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/1249976/sendkeys-method-in-powershell/1250038)**

Comment: I'm using Selenium with Pythoh in a *nix environment in headless mode.

Comment: Why not give a try in linux/python with **[pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)**

Answer (score 0):

When you are lacking a means of supplying the proxy with user-name and password,
you could perhaps solve this by using a two-step proxy :

1. A local proxy server on your computer without user-name and password
2. The local proxy should connect to the real external proxy using the user-name and password.

A possible solution is installing [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) together with
[proxy-password-automator](https://github.com/sjitech/proxy-login-automator), but this depends on your environment.

If you don't have a suitable proxy product, or if the above does not relate
to your environment, I would need more detail about the
environment to suggest a suitable one.